# able to connect to remote mongodb atlas cluster from my command line but not from docker app

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-atlas

already tried whitelisting ip address `0.0.0.0/0` for the cluster, but my Go app on my local machine nor on my remote server are able to talk to it

error:

```
api_1        | 2020/12/28 23:36:35 stdout: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AtlasError) bad auth : Authentication failed.
```

calling `mongodb+srv://username:password@mars.in8bc.mongodb.net/MY_DB`, I'm using a user that has full database read/write access

anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Does the username or password contain any characters that would be interpreted as a variable by Docker, or that need to be URL encoded?

Comment: nope, just plain words